# Consistency and efficiency for vector estimator.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, parameter-estimation, estimation

I would like to know if there is the definition of something as consistency and efficiency for vector estimator.

Probably the definition of consistency can be generalized, it means that
$\forall \varepsilon>0: \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}P\left(\{\omega \in \Omega: ||T_n-\theta||<\varepsilon\}\right)=0$,
where $||\cdot||$ is Euclidean norm, $\theta$ is $k$-dimensional vector of parameters and $T_n$ is vector estimator of $\theta$.

But there is the theorem for one-dimensional parameter $\theta$ which says: Consider that $E(T^2_n)<\infty$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Moreover $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}E(T_n)=\theta$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}D(T_n)=0$, then one-dimensional estimator $T_n$ is consitent estimator of one-dimensional pramater $\theta$.

Is there something similar for vector estimator $T_n$ of vector parameter $\theta$?

And moreover can be difient something like efficiency for vector estimator? I know that Rao-Cramer bound exist also for vector estimator so maybe for unbiased vector estimator the efficiency can be defined as $I(\theta)^{-1}var^{-1}(T_n)$, but this expression is matrix. How is it "measure efficiency"?

If something like this exists, can you recommend some literature? I cannot find any relevant source in the internet.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is $D(T_n)$?

Comment: Dispersion or variance of random variable.

Comment: A sequence $\{T_n\}$ of random vectors is (weakly) consistent for $\theta$ if $\lVert T_n-\theta\rVert$ converges in probability to $0$. So a sufficient condition for this to hold is $\operatorname E_{\theta}\lVert T_n-\theta\rVert \to 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}_{\theta}\lVert T_n-\theta\rVert\to 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you recommend me some literature which deals with these things? Everything which I have found was about scalar parameter $\theta$.